# What is the largest number of elements in a subset of $\{1,2,3, \ldots, N\}$ such that the sum of every pair of distinct elements in it is different?

Tags: combinatorics

The original question from my textbook was

> What is the largest number of elements in a subset of $\{1,2,3, \ldots, 9\}$ such that the sum of every pair of distinct elements in the subset is different?

I got the answer $5$ purely by trying out a few combinations.

I would like to know how to solve it mathematically, and also how we can generalise this up till the $N$th natural number.

Comment: Some trial and error (just up to 13, and error-prone) leads me to believe that picking out the Fibonacci numbers might be the best possible choice. I have no idea yet whether that's true, or why it would be so.

Comment: Yes, I realised that too. I'm thinking the best possible scenario is to start from 1 and then take 2 terms in Arithmetic progression and upping the common difference by 1 and then repeating. For example 1,2,3,5,7,10,13,17,21,26,31....because having any more than 3 terms in AP will lead to them adding up to the same number...The Fibonacci sequence might not be the most efficient as we take a larger $N$

Comment: 1,2,3,5,7 falls into 1+7=3+5. So you can't pick 7 at that stage. That means 8. Next, neither 9, 10, 11 nor 12 may be picked, so the next possible number is 13, and you're on the track to Fibonacci. This is as far as I took it (I don't didn't check whether 21 is the next possible choice). Also, there is no guarantee that this greedy algorithm actually produces the best answer.

Comment: Shoudn't the question title be changed from "What is the largest number of subsets" into "What is the largest number of elements in a subset"?

Comment: @Billy Joe Yes, you are right! Thanks for pointing it out. Changing the title now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generalization is an open problem related to [Sidon sequences](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidon_sequence), also called $B_2$ sequences.

As pointed out by Misha Lavrov it is possible to get subsets with $O(\sqrt{N})$ elements.

See also a similar question in Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10557152/7231208) where I got the reference to Sidon sequences and where you see e.g. that any $b^0, b^1, ... b^m \le N$ with $b \ge 2$ is a Sidon sequence, but the Fibonacci series seems optimal (only for small values of $N$!).

Comment: I'd point out that exponential sequences like the Fibonacci sequence will be very bad for large $N$: you will only pick out $\Theta(\log N)$ numbers that way, but it's actually possible to get $\Theta(\sqrt N)$.

Comment: @Misha Lavrov yes, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

$5$ is the largest cardinality. A set of $5$ elements is $\{1,2,3,5,8\}$ (as you already noted it contains Fibonacci numbers).

If we have a subset $S$ with $6$ elements such that the sum of every pair of distinct elements in $S$ is different then the number of such values is $\binom{6}{2}=15$. On the other hand, by summing two different numbers in $\{1,2,3,\dots,9\}$ we obtain $15$ different numbers: $3,4,5,\dots,17$. Since we have $15$ distinct values among $15$, we must have them all.
Therefore  we have $3$, which can be obtained only as $1+2$, and $17$, which can be obtained only as $8+9$. Hence $1,2,8,9\in S$ and we have a contradiction because $1+9=2+8=10$.

Comment: Nice, +1. Perhaps your answer would be clearer if you added the explicit explanation "we have 15 distinct values among 15, so we must have them all". I didn't realize it at once, at first I wondered what was so special about 3 and 17 ...

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Thanks for your comment. I edited my answer. Is it better now?

Comment: sure ! Thank you for trusting me and applying my suggestion so literally :-)

Comment: Nice! I think the set (1,2,3,5,8) works up till N=12, at 13 we than have a set with cardinality 6. So what I don't understand is how to calculate that largest cardinality set for a set upto the general Nth natural number...A starting point could be assuming the set starts with (1,2,3,5,8,....) but I don't know how to prove that either...

Comment: @Maven I tried to generalize the same approach unsuccessfully :-(